# Can I find price floors and ceilings with cuda

Tags: cuda, thrust

#### Background

I'm trying to convert an algorithm from sequential to parallel, but I am stuck.

#### Point and Figure Charts

[image: Point and Figure Chart]

I am creating point and figure charts.

**Decreasing**
While the stock is going down, add an O every time it breaks through the floor.

**Increasing**
While the stock is going up, add an X every time it breaks through the ceiling.

**Reversal**
If the stock reverses direction, but the change is less than a reversal threshold (3 units) do nothing. If the change is greater than the reversal threshold, start a new column (X or O)

#### Sequential vs Parallel

Sequentially, this is pretty straight forward. I keep a variable for the floor and ceiling. If the current price breaks through the floor or ceiling, or changes more than the reversal threshold, I can take the appropriate action.

My question is, is there a way to find these reversal point in parallel? I'm fairly new to thinking in parallel, so I'm sorry if this is trivial. I am trying to do this in CUDA, but I have been stuck for weeks. I have tried using the [finite difference](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/finite-difference-methods-cuda-cc-part-1/) algorithms from NVidia. These produce local max / min but not the reversal points. Small fluctuations produce numerous relative max / min, but most of them are trivial because the change is not greater than the reversal size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, is there a way to find these reversal point in parallel?

one possible approach:

1. use thrust::unique to remove periods where the price is numerically constant
2. use thrust::adjacent_difference to produce 1st difference data
3. use thrust::adjacent_difference on 1st difference data to get the 2nd difference data, i.e the points where there is a change in the sign of the slope.
4. use these points of change in sign of slope to identify separate regions of data - build a key vector from these (e.g. with a prefix sum).  This key vector segments the price data into "runs" where the price change is in a particular direction.
5. use thrust::exclusive_scan_by_key on the 1st difference data, to produce the net change of the run
6. Wherever the net change of the run exceeds a threshold, flag as a "reversal"

Your description of what constitutes a reversal may also be slightly unclear.  The above method would not flag a reversal on certain data patterns that you might classify as a reversal.  I suspect you are looking beyond a single run as I have defined it here.  If that is the case, there may be a method to address that as well - with more steps.

Comment: You are correct, I am looking at lengths longer than a single "run" as defined here. So if a price drops by 2, increases by 1, and then drops by another 2 .. it should count as decreasing by 3 total. 

A stock should be decreasing until it has risen at least 3 dollars above the most recent floor. Decreasing further moves the floor down.

Thanks for your answer, it really helped. Hopefully I clarified what I mean by reversal. Otherwise [this](https://youtu.be/ysas8DO9mWI?t=87) video might explain it better.

Comment: There's no need to accept my answer if it doesn't meet your needs.